# Passing a capture group in query parameters in NGINX URI

Tags: regex, nginx

In NGINX, is there any way to pass a capture group in a query parameter for a rewrite outside of a location block, such as this?  Thanks!

```
if ($request_uri = /abc/def?query=(.*) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /123/$1? permanent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below should work for you

```
if ($request_uri ~ "/abc/def\?query=") {
      rewrite ^.*$ /123/$arg_query/? permanent;
}
```